# visual studio templates update not successful

Tags: visual-studio, templates

When creating a new project, there are a lot of options in the template...
How do you add more templates to  Visual Studio Project.  I tried to update, but it did not work.

I saw one version with a lot of items, like Web forms application, MVC web application, ...

And mine is only showing: asp.net web application...

[image]

[image]

[edit] **and how do you add the blue template from VS2013 (with your logo here), instead of this black template in VS2017.**
[image]

Comment: In newer Visual Studio versions there is one shared template for ASP.NET, and after selecting it you can choose what *kind* of ASP.NET project you want : Web Forms, MVC, Web API, ...

Comment: yes, the black one is VS2013, the white one is VS2017...  oh ok...  because ther was also the possibility to add an extra folder to web for VS2012 in VS2013

Comment: and how do you use the blue template form VS2013 instead of the black one in VS2017, in VS2017.

Comment: You can't use the old ones, and you don't need them either. MVC is now a NuGet package. The ASP.NET template will add the MVC NuGet package to the Web project (if you select MVC of course) and then VS+NuGet will download and install the latest MVC version into your project. You may also be offered package updates if new MVC versions are released.